# Aggregation including keys and values for Flattened field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Let say, I have this document:

```
  POST bug_reports/_doc/1
  {
    "title": "Results are not sorted correctly.",
    "labels": {
      "priority": "urgent",
      "product": "A"
    }
  }
```

`labels` field is flattened which means we don't know the number/name of keys.

If I get an aggregation, it gives me something like this for buckets:

```
{
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "urgent",
      "doc_count": 27705
    },
    {
      "key": "no urgent",
      "doc_count": 705
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is the expected result but I want to create an aggregation including keys, values and doc_count for every key inside the flattened field. An example:

```
{
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "priority",
      "values": [
        {
          "key": "urgent",
          "doc_count": 27705
        },
        {
          "key": "no urgent",
          "doc_count": 705
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "product",
      "values": [
        {
          "key": "A",
          "doc_count": 3215
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this possible? I've checked docs related to `composite` and `multi_terms` aggregation but they seem to be for different use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple aggregations in one query. For example:

```
GET bug_reports/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "priority_key": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "labels.priority",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "product_key": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "labels.product",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's impossible to aggregate `all fields inside an object automatically` but you can find and define before aggregation.

```
GET bug_reports/_mapping/field/labels.*?filter_path=*.*.*.full_name
```

The response:

```
{
  "bug_reports": {
    "mappings": {
      "labels.priority": {
        "full_name": "labels.priority"
      },
      "labels.product": {
        "full_name": "labels.product"
      }
    }
  }
}
```